# Consuming Task based async WCF web service from Android

Tags: c#, java, android, wcf

Is it possible to consume Task based async WCF web service methods from **Android**? Any sample code will be appreciated. I could not find any Android sample when I googled.

**Edit:**

I would specifically like Android to consume a WCF service like below.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMessage
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<string> GetMessages(string msg);
}
```

Comment: How the web service is implemented doesn't matter. Just look up how to call a web service, or WCF service.

Comment: @TimS. I do not think this is a duplicate of that post. See my edit. AFAIK Task<> is something specific to C#. So I am exploring to see if someone was able to consume this in Android.

Comment: @svrcoder, as far as the client is concerned, calling an operation defined as `Task<string> GetMessage(string msg)` is **exactly** the same as calling an operation defined as `string GetMessage(string msg)`. The networking request required to call both operations are the same (and the response should be the same as well).

Comment: To second what @carlosfigueira said, I have just verified that the WSDLs/XSDs generated by those two signatures (`Task<string>` and `string`) are the same - thus, it looks exactly the same to the client.